# How to edit search icon on search form?

Tags: magento2, design

In responsive mode, I can inspect element to see class and values of the search icon.

However in "desktop" mode, when inspecting element I haven't found the corresponding class to edit the search icon.

I know magento 2 uses font icons. I don't want to replace the icon. I just want to edit the color and size.

I created a custom theme which inherits from the Blank magento theme.

Comment: Which template are you using?

Comment: A custom theme which inherits from the Blank theme

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below css:

```
.block-search .action.search:before {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

I find the icon seems to dim for me however not quite sure why yet.

Comment: How did you find this class?